# Non-resolvable parent POM using Maven 3.0.3 and relativePath notation

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml

After migrating to Mavent 3.0.3 Parent poms in several Projects cannot be resolved anymore.

The Projects are structured in a default manner, so I set
parent.relativePath to "../pom.xml"

```
superpom (located in repository)
|-rootpom (located locally: no error)
|-|-parentpom (located locally: error resolving parent)
|-|-|-module1 (located locally: error resolving parent)
|-|-|-module2 (located locally: error resolving parent)
|-|-|-module3 (located locally: error resolving parent)
|-|-|-module4 (located locally: error resolving parent)
```

The Error...

> Non-resolvable parent POM for myGroup:myArtifactId:1.0:  Failure to
> find myGroup:myParentArtifactId:1.0 in
> http://myRepo.net/archiva/repository/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resollution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced and
> 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @
> myGroup:myParentArtifactId:1.0, C:\myProjectDir\parent\pom.xml, line
> x, column y -> [Help 2]

... seems to indicate that the pom was searched for in the repository, so I wonder why the pom was not found locally before looked elsewhere.

I have read that maven3 might get confused when several repositories are defined in the settings.xml, but that was always when searching for a pom inside repositories and not locally.

**update**

Up until now we did execute the maven build on the parent-project level (parentpom) - a fact which I did not know was important, since maven2 completed successfully until now.

When using maven3 this seems to be of importance.
When executing maven3 on the root-project level (rootpom) the build finishes successfully.
So my immediate problem is solved.

> Since I don't necessarily want to answer my own question maybe
> someone can explain why maven3 behaves this way now or why the old
> approach was wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to set `relativePath` just the folder name? (e.g. `../`, without `pom.xml`)

Comment: i have tried ".." "../pom.xml" and now "../"

Answer (score 34):

Make sure you Double-Check that the version you refer to in the child-pom is the same as that in the parent-pom.   For me, I'd bumped version in the parent and had it as 3.1.0.0-RELEASE, but in the child-pom, I was still referring to the previous version via relativePath, and had it defined as 2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.   It did not make any difference if I included just the parent directory, or had the "pom.xml" appended to the directory:

```
    <parent>        
    <artifactId>eric-project-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.eric.common</groupId>
     <!-- Should be 3.1.0.0-RELEASE -->
    <version>2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>     
    <relativePath>
                ../../EricParentAsset/projects/eric-project-parent</relativePath>           
</parent>
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003831/parent-relativepath-points-at-my-com-mycompanymyproject-instead-of-org-apache) to your question.

By default maven looks in `../pom.xml` for `relativePath`. Use empty `<relativePath/>` tag instead.

Comment: Wouldn't `<relativePath>./pom.xml<relativePath>` work as well but be clearer to the next person looking through this POM?

Comment: ArtB, you offer to set current project's pom as a parent pom. For me this is more confusing then empty string. I expect that this would not just work.

Here is what is written in [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_parent):
_Set the value to an empty string in case you want to disable the feature and always resolve the parent POM from the repositories_

Answer (score 6):

> 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @
>   myGroup:myParentArtifactId:1.0, ***C:\myProjectDir\parent\pom.xml***

This indicates that maven did search locally for the parent pom, but found that it was not the correct pom.

- Does `pom.xml` of `parentpom` correctly define the `parent` pom as the `pom.xml` of `rootpom`?
- Does `rootpom` folder contain `pom.xml` as well as the `paretpom` folder?

Comment: Yes, the parent of my parent-project is correctly defined as the root-project (version,artifact-id,group-id and relative path) and the root-project folder contains the parent-project folder. The projects did build correctly with maven2. I just added the relativePath after switching to maven3.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  My project layout looked like

```
\---super
    \---thirdparty
        +---mod1-root
        |   +---mod1-linux32
        |   \---mod1-win32
        \---mod2-root
            +---mod2-linux32
            \---mod2-win32
```

In my case, I had a mistake in my pom.xmls at the modX-root-level.  I had copied the mod1-root tree and named it mod2-root.  I incorrectly thought I had updated all the pom.xmls appropriately; but in fact, mod2-root/pom.xml had the same group and artifact ids as mod1-root/pom.xml.  After correcting mod2-root's pom.xml to have mod2-root specific maven coordinates my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your relative path, based on depth of your modules from parent if module is just below parent then in module put relative path as:
../pom.xml

if its 2 level down then
../../pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please check in logs if you have http.HttpWagon$__sisu1:Cannot find 'basicAuthScope'  this error or warning also, if so you need to use maven 3.2.5 version, which will resolve error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.test.vaquar.khan</groupId>
        <artifactId>vk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../projectname/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

Add following line in parent

```
<relativePath>../projectname/pom.xml</relativePath>
```

You need relative path if you are building from local parent pom not available in nexsus, add pom in nexus then no need this path

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works when I double checked the parent´s "group ID" and "artifact ID" that in my case were the wrong ones and that was the problem.