# Jenkins build failure due to use of custom jars in maven project

Tags: jenkins

I am having a trouble while building my java maven project in jenkins.
In my project, there are few custom jars which I included in pom like this

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>SMSGatewayClient</groupId>
        <artifactId>SMSGatewayClient</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\lib\SMSGatewayClient.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

But jenkins throwing exception

> "Could not find artifact SMSGatewayClient:SMSGatewayClient:jar:1.0 at
>   specified path
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEV-metal-auc/MetalBusiness_mvn\lib\SMSGatewayClient.jar"

and build is stopped.

How can I use that custom jar so that jenkins builds successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using ”/" path separators (or `${file.separator}` ) in the path?

Your error shows a mix and `/var/lib/` suggests you are on unix.

That assumes the `${basedir}` resolved correctly.

You can also use relative notation ( `../` ) and is probably preferred if inside your workspace. You may wish to review [Maven complaining about parent relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062491/maven-complaining-about-parent-relative-path) and  [Maven: add a dependency to a jar by relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path)

In maven, "`${basedir}` represents the directory containing pom.xml", so
`<relativePath>./lib</relativePath>`. If you had to fo up,and down, `../` for each level up, then path down.

Comment: Please mention what should be the above path after using relative notation.

Comment: Added notes. Main point is use `/`, not `\` in the pom.mxl, regaedless of path type.. `\` is a Unix escape character.