# 'parent.relativePath' of imported bill-of materials POM creating warning in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-bom

Note that this question is about a `parent.relativePath` warning in an **imported bill-of-materials (BOM)**, not in the hierarchy of my own POM as with ['parent.relativePath' points at my com.mycompany:MyProject instead of org.apache:apache - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003831).

In Eclipse EE 2022-09 using Java 17 I have a a project with a main POM that extends from our own root POM:

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>com.globalmentor</groupId>
  <artifactId>globalmentor-root</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.13</version>
</parent>
```

The main POM also brings in dependencies from a bill of materials POM (which we also published):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.clogr</groupId>
  <artifactId>clogr-bom</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.3</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

When viewing the POM as source, Eclipse shows this warning:

> 'parent.relativePath' of POM io.clogr:clogr-bom:0.8.3 points at io.clogr:clogr-bom instead of com.globalmentor:globalmentor-base, please verify your project structure pom.xml /foo-bar

(In case it is relevant, note that I also have the actual source of `io.clogr:clogr-bom` imported into Eclipse as a separate project.)

I am aware of the purpose of `relativePath` as used in my own POM and parent POM. But this warning seems to be saying that the it doesn't like the `relativePath` designation of *the imported BOM*! Nevertheless the warning references line 5 of my main POM, which is the designation of the parent POM (`com.globalmentor:globalmentor-root`). Moreover look closely at the error message: it says that the relative path of `io.clogr:clogr-bom` points to itself! This cannot be the case, as `io.clogr:clogr-bom` has no relative path designation, and the default I understand is `../pom.xml`. There is no way I can think of that `io.clogr:clogr-bom` could have its relative path pointing at `io.clogr:clogr-bom` itself.

1. Why is there a warning for the `relativePath` of an imported BOM, yet the warning references the line for the *parent* POM coordinates?
2. How do I fix this: by publishing a new `io.clog:clogr-bom` using `<relativePath />`?
3. But if I publish a new a new `io.clog:clogr-bom` using `<relativePath />`, does that mean the children of `io.clog:clogr-bom` need to add an explicit `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` on the aggregated children of `io.clog:clogr-bom` because they are now inheriting a relative path from `io.clog:clogr-bom`, or will they stil get a default of `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` because the relative path does not inherit?

Comment: "*How do I fix this: by ... using `<relativePath />`?*" Seems wrong. What purpose is relative path to a consumer? It's defining a relative path within the source project. It's used to build the project. A consumer doesn't care about that. The project is already built. Why not flatten the POM with the flatten plugin? It gets rid of a lot of unnecessary junk for consumers, including the entire `<parent>` declaration. It specifically has a mode for BOMs.

Comment: Can you please show the directory structure or even better making an example project which shows that behaviour...?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is right: your bom is incorrect, let's elaborate that...

1. in order to build module pom (project object model, do not confuse with pom.xml) `maven` needs to know where the parent pom.xml is located (if parent is specified), and here we may raise a question: why do we need to specify both parent GAV coordinates (group-artifact-version) and relativePath? And the rationale is following:

   - `maven` may locate artifact using GAV coordinates only when that artifact was installed/published in local/remote repository, if that didn't happen `maven` obviously fails (example: we are bootstrapping new multi-module project)
   - technically, there is no strict requirement to publish parent pom files (for example, parent/aggregator pom files may contain some information about our build process and we do not want to expose such information), moreover, there is no requirement for parent modules to be a part of reactor, however in that case you **must use** `flatten-maven-plugin` when installing/publishing such artifacts
2. `maven` resolves parent's pom.xml using following algorithm:

   - if `relativePath` is "specified" `maven` uses it, please note, the absence of `relativePath` element means that `relativePath` is `../pom.xml` (that is your case) - to nullify the value of `relativePath` you need to place `<relativePath/>` element into parent configuration
   - otherwise `maven` tries to locate parent pom.xml using GAV coordinates in local repository and in case of failure in remote repositories
3. so, the general recommendations when dealing with parents are following:

   - if parent module is a part of multi-module project set the correct value of `relativePath` (relying on default `../pom.xml` is not good idea though)
   - if parent module is a not part of multi-module project nullify `relativePath` via specifying `<relativePath/>`
   - take advantage of `flatten-maven-plugin`

In regard to your [`clogr-bom`](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/clogr/clogr-bom/0.8.3/clogr-bom-0.8.3.pom) - that is definitely not a `Bill Of Materials`, it is just a published aggregator module, in order to be a bom it's content should be following:

```xml
 <groupId>io.clogr</groupId>
 <artifactId>clogr-bom</artifactId>
 <version>0.8.3</version>
 <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <name>Clogr BOM</name>
 <description>Parent POM and bill of materials of all Clogr projects.</description>
 <url>https://clogr.io/</url>
 <inceptionYear>2016</inceptionYear>

 <licenses>
  <license>
   <name>Apache-2.0</name>
   <url>https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
   <distribution>repo</distribution>
  </license>
 </licenses>

 <organization>
  <name>GlobalMentor, Inc.</name>
  <url>https://www.globalmentor.com/</url>
 </organization>

 <developers>
  …
 </developers>

 <scm>
  <connection>scm:git:https://bitbucket.org/globalmentor/clogr.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:https://bitbucket.org/globalmentor/clogr.git</developerConnection>
  <url>https://bitbucket.org/globalmentor/clogr</url>
 </scm>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.clogr</groupId>
    <artifactId>clogr</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.clogr</groupId>
    <artifactId>clogr-logback</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.clogr</groupId>
    <artifactId>clogr-logback-provider</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>io.clogr</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j1-shim</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
   </dependency>

  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

---

UPD.

Q: Thus any POM that will be published as a parent POM or to be imported needs `<relativePath/>`

A: My opinion on that is following: any published artifact, which is not intended to be `parent` in any project **must** strip-off information about parent (that is not just about `relativePath` element, but about the entire `parent` element), the rationale is following:

when we consume external dependency, the only information which makes sense for us is it's transitive dependencies, on the other hand specifying parent in external dependency forces `maven` to resolve that parent as well, and, unfortunately, that process is error-prone because parent may reside in unreachable repository, may contain mistakes, etc - such glitches are pretty common for projects, which we are considering now as "legacy", however, anything what we are doing now will eventually turn into "legacy" as well.

Q: Who says an aggregate POM cannot also serve as a bill of materials by being imported into another project?

A: I do :) Well, actually there is no common opinion about "what is BoM" even [across maven team](https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/689), however I would prefer to share my opinion with Robert Scholte and consider "BoM" as a "Table Of Contents":

> To me a BOM represents only the set of modules of a multimodule, that contain the versions that work together. This should prevent issues with dependency depth/distance which could pull in an unexpected version.
> Ideally all multimodules also provide a BOM.
> Other dependencies don't belong here, as they should be upgradable/downgradable independent of the BOM.

Comment: Thanks for the time to write all this out. 1) Just to clarify: to fix this you're saying that I need to add `<relativePath/>` to `io.clogr:clogr-bom` (regardless of what I call it)? 2) Will adding `<relativePath/>` to `io.clogr:clogr-bom` require I add `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` to _its_ children (ie. is `<relativePath>` inherited?), or do they still get that by default? 3) Thus _any_ POM that will be published as a parent POM or to be imported needs `<relativePath/>`? 4) Who says an aggregate POM cannot also serve as a bill of materials by being imported into another project?

Comment: 1) yes.  2) No, child modules do not inherit `<parent>` element from parent (that is kind of reasonable behaviour: to inherit something from parent we need to discover parent first), however it is worth to specify `relativePath` in child modules to prevent further confusion. 3) 4) - please check UPD.

Comment: "child modules do not inherit `<parent>` element from parent (that is kind of reasonable behaviour: to inherit something from parent we need to discover parent first)" hahaha Oh, you're right. Still, one never knows with Maven. It likes to inherit everything. (See [MNG-7562](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-7562).)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that your definition of a BOM is your opinion, not something official. It's a valid opinion, and in a perfect world perhaps a BOM _should_ be a little more focused than mine, but I'm being pragmatic. I don't have the time to create some separate POM for every aggregated project, and I wanted an easy way for users to get the correct versions without the unwieldy and problematic `<foo.version>` mechanism. To me if it includes all versions of the project modules, and a user can successfully `import` it, it can function as a BOM—a "table of contents with a few extras".

Comment: "**must** strip-off information about parent (that is not just about `relativePath` element, but about the entire `parent` element) …". Can you clarify what you mean about stripping off the entire `parent` element? We have a common `globalmentor-root` POM (see question) which does a _lot_ of heavy lifting and is thus ultimately inherited by _all_ our POMs. How could we publish an artifact that strips off the parent element, when it must specify that `globalmentor-root` is its parent?

Comment: You still didn't explain what you meant when you said "strip-off information about parent".

Comment: @GarretWilson you have mentioned you have no time to manage things properly, why are you asking me to waste my time?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a forum for posting questions and soliciting answers. I appreciate your taking the time to post an answer, but part of your response was unclear. I asked for clarification on your response. Whether I have time to make major changes to my projects is a separate issue then whether we have time to have a conversation on Stack Overflow. I have time to have a conversation with you on Stack Overflow. Do you have time to have a conversation? It may not result in my changing my projects, but it furthers sharing of ideas, which is the purpose of this forum.